# jetty listening on UDP Port

Tags: ubuntu, udp, jetty, port

It seems that jetty application server is listening on random udp ports (range somewhere between 30000 and 50000)

```
$ netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
..
udp        0      0 *:35462                 *:*


$ lsof -i :35462
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    6895 jetty  60u  IPv4  49201      0t0  UDP *:35462
```

any idea what this is (and if it can be deactivated)?

Thanks and best regards
Holger

Comment: Thanks, joakim for the formatting you've been faster than me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behavior for the Connectors is to only listen on the appropriate tcp (tcp4 or tcp6) ports that you specify in your configuration.

However, there are other features you can enable both in Jetty itself, and within your webapp that might cause more ports to listen.

Things to look for in your setup.

- You have STOP.PORT defined for supporting shell based stop of Jetty (this should only be listening on localhost btw)
- JMX enabled
- JDBC configurations (some JDBC drivers open up more ports for incoming connections)
- NoSQL configurations
- other RMI based configurations

This is by far not an exhaustive list, but should open your eyes to the possibilities.

Another tip, use the `-p` command line option with netstat to find all open ports by pid easier.

```
$ jps -mlv
11944 start.jar
12030 sun.tools.jps.Jps -mlv -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u21-x64 -Xms8m

$ netstat -anp | grep 11944
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11944/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      11944/java      
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     39525679 11944/java
```

Comment: Thanks - it's the stop port which can be specified through -DSTOP.PORT. If not jetty uses a random port.